# Get month function return wrong value

Tags: javascript

I used script to change from TIMESTAMP in Oracle from Json to dd/mm/yy, but the function getMonth of javascript return month fail. In example below, the Month is 3 but it return is 2. Why? Please help.

```js
    var date = "/Date(1520996412000)/";
    var fullDate = new Date(date.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
    var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth() + "";
    console.log(fullDate);
    console.log(twoDigitMonth);
```

Comment: Month is 0 index based

Comment: getMonth() return value considering Jan = 0 and Dec = 11

Comment: FYI month begin from 0 to 11 https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMonth()` method's return value:

An integer number, between 0 and 11, representing the month in the given date according to local time. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (**where zero indicates the first month of the year**).

Comment: Thanks. This mean we need set twoDigitMonth = twoDigitMonth + 1?

Comment: If you are wanting your months to be represented as 1-12 as instead of 0-11, then yes you are correct.